# how to select proprely on psql

Tags: php, postgresql

**
I hope my explanation will make sense. On my (cursosprogramas) psql table I have the column disciplina. I want every time I select any disciplina on the other select/drop down  option it gives me only the option to select two or one number which are on the rows diurno and pos_laboral. Sample you select any name on the disciplina drop down it will show the numbers available on the docente drop down
Like I’ll select vacinas and The output of it will be 5 and 4 (which 5 is in diurnos row)  and (4 on row pos_laboral).

Honestly I do not know how to it.
Any help please
**

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtBM5.png)

*my code*

```
<form class="modal-content animate" action="addhorarios.php" method="POST">
Disciplina
<select style="width: 300px; font-size: 12px" type=text name=disciplina selected><br>

  <?php
  
  $sql2 = "select * from cursosprogramas where codigocurso ='$grdid' ;";
  $res2 = pg_query ($con, $sql2);

  for ($i= 0; $i < pg_numrows($res2);$i++) {
    $disciplina = pg_fetch_result ($res2, $i, "disciplina");
    $ms = pg_fetch_result ($res2, $i, "ms");
    echo "<option value = $disciplina>$disciplina -Ms$ms</option>";
  }
  ?>
</select>

<label style="margin-left: 30px">Docente </label> 
<select style="width: 300px; font-size: 12px;" type=text name=professor><br>

  <?php

  $sql2 = "select * from cursosprogramas where codigocurso ='$grdid' ;";
  $res2 = pg_query ($con, $sql2);

  for ($i= 0; $i < pg_numrows($res2);$i++) {
    $diurno = pg_fetch_result ($res2, $i, "diurno");
    echo "<option value = $diurno>$diurno";
    $pos_laboral = pg_fetch_result ($res2, $i, "pos_laboral");
    echo "<option value = $pos_laboral>$pos_laboral</option>";
  }
  ?>

</select>
```

Comment: Please add a small example of input data and expected output data (in text mode: try to avoid to post pictures if it is not reallty needed).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @pifor. Sample , I will select vacinas which is inside the table on row disciplina and the output of it will be will be number 5 (which is in row diurno) and 4 (which is on row pos_laboral).